# How to pass model from partialView to javascript in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I wanna pass down model from partialView to javascript and process it in controller,
now the problem is i couldn't pass the model where when i run the code it show null. can anyone help me on this?

*HTML code

```
@model List<TPMS.Models.Draft_SingleValue>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>

                <tr class="bg-gray">

                    <th>Keyword</th>
                    <th>Default Value <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></span></th>

                    <th><span class="pull-right"><i></i></span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var sdata in Model.OrderBy(i => i.Keyword))
                {
                    <tr id="@sdata.DraftSingleValue_ID">

                        <td id="sv:@sdata.DraftSingleValue_ID:Keyword" contenteditable="false">@sdata.Keyword</td>

                        <td id="sv:@sdata.DraftSingleValue_ID:Default_Value" contenteditable="false"> @sdata.Default_Value</td>

                        <td id="sv:@sdata.DraftSingleValue_ID" contenteditable="false" class="">
                            <span class="btn-group center-block" id="PlusButton">
                                <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="javascript:AddKeyword('@sdata');"  data-id="@sdata"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </a>
                            </span>
                        </td>  

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr class="bg-gray">

                    <th>Keyword</th>
                    <th>Default_Value <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></span></th>

                    <th><span class="pull-right"><i></i></span></th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Javascript

```
 function AddKeyword(SvModel) {

            debugger
            //var model = $('#Testing').attr('data-id');

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("AddSingleValue", "Draft")",
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                datatype: 'html',
                data: {"Model": SvModel },

                success: function (data) {

                    $('#List_Keyword').modal('hide');
                    $("#List_SVKeywords").html(data);
                    $('#List_Keyword').modal('show');

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve values.');
                    document.getElementById("del_err_span_dialog").innerHTML = "Fatal Error, Please try again.";
                }
            });


        }
```

*Controller

```
 public ActionResult AddSingleValue(Draft_SingleValue Model)
        {

            Draft_SingleValue svmodel = new Draft_SingleValue();

            svmodel.Draft_File_ID = Model.Draft_File_ID;
            svmodel.Data_Type = Model.Data_Type;
            svmodel.Group_Name = Model.Group_Name;
            svmodel.Is_Active = Model.Is_Active;
            svmodel.Keyword = Model.Keyword;
            svmodel.Max_Length = Model.Max_Length;
            svmodel.Min_Length = Model.Min_Length;
            svmodel.Modified_By = User.Identity.Name;
            svmodel.Modified_On = DateTime.Now;
            svmodel.Remarks = Model.Remarks;
            svmodel.Default_Value = Model.Default_Value;

                _temporaryrepo.Insert_TemporarySingleValue(svmodel);


            return ListSv(svmodel.Draft_File_ID);

            //return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

As you guys can c from above code, im trying to pass model to AddKeyword function but i cant. it will be great if anyone can show me a way to do this.

Comment: What is the value of `SvModel`? You cannot pass a complex model like that

Comment: 1) Why (in the C#) are you re-creating a whole new `Draft_SingleValue` object (svmodel) which is identical to the one being sent in the request? Seems totally pointless, you're just creating a carbon copy (except for the Modified_By / On properties), but you could just set these properties on the original object) to no obvious purpose. 2) `javascript:AddKeyword('@sdata');` just seems to pass (some string representation of) the original model, not what gets typed in. You need to serialise the form and send that, I think, although it's not very clear from the code what the real intent its

Comment: @StephenMuecke its contents values from database. e.g(keyword = hash,datatype = string,value = 8589888 and etc.)

Comment: No its not. Add `console.log({"Model": SvModel });` in your script and inspect the output to understand. And even if you did serialize it correctly, all you are doing is passing back the identical object you just sent to the view (i.e. it would be pointless). What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: @ADyson yea.i know im recreating because im not sure how to update specific field which is modified_by. the model im getting in the view is from database. im trying to get data from different table and insert to another table. in modal view i am passing the value to javascript. where i need to add in the value when user click add button.

Comment: @StephenMuecke actually im passing on list of model to the view, and from there user need to choose which keyword to add in to the database. each keyword is in one model where i need to pass back to controller to add in database.

Comment: " im not sure how to update specific field which is modified_by. " ...`Model.Modified_By = User.Identity.Name; Model.Modified_On = DateTime.Now;` . Just like any other object. There is nothing particularly special about the input variable in that sense. Duplicating the whole object just for that is a waste of code and RAM

Comment: "each keyword is in one model where i need to pass back to controller to add in database." So it sounds like probably all you really need to send back to the server is the ID related to the keyword?

Comment: Sorry, but still not clear. Your view does not even include any editable form controls so its not clear what you want to send to the server. Best guess is you want to pass the ID of your `Draft_SingleValue` model and then you get the object based on the ID and update

Comment: @ADyson thanks, i think i need to rewrite back my logic again.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks . i will just change my logic and try

Comment: @sean Could you please try the approach given in my answer below and let me know if it works? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @MuratYıldız i tried your code but i couldnt get it work,  i have change my logic as stephen and ADyson suggested where i only pass the ID's  and process it on backend. the problem i faced running you suggestion is, im using a modal the view all the data by row. so each row contain each model. i just need pass down single model only at a time, but when using Html.BeginForm, it passes whole list of model. anyway. thanks for the suggestions. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourActionMethod", "YourController", FormMethod.Post,
    new { id = "frmCreate", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{       
    //code omitted for brevity
}

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var formdata = new FormData($('#frmCreate').get(0));
         
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("YourActionMethod", "YourController")',
                data: formdata, //! your model data
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        //success
                    }
                    else {
                        //error
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult YourActionMethod([Bind(Exclude = null)] Model viewModel)
{
    //...
    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Success!.." }, 
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```